# Get categories query not working in function.php

Tags: custom-field, categories

I am trying to get the categories of my custom post type in functions.php But it not return any value, when i run this query in any theme file it work fine. Here is my code

```
function get_destinations(){
   $args = array(
    'type'                     => 'accomodation',
    'child_of'                 => 0,
    'parent'                   => '',
    'orderby'                  => 'name',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 1,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'exclude'                  => '',
    'include'                  => '',
    'number'                   => '',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'facilitie',
    'pad_counts'               => false 

); 
 $categories = get_categories($args);$destinations = array();
              foreach ($categories as $cat) { 
                if($cat->cat_name != ''){
                    $destinations[$cat->cat_name] = $cat->cat_name;
                }
          }
return $destinations;
 }
```

I am using [this](https://en.bainternet.info/how-i-add-a-wordpress-metabox/) code to add `meta field`, now i have to pass the category to `select` tag which is

```
$my_meta2->addSelect($prefix.'select_field_id',get_destinations(),array('name'=> 'Select Destination'));
```

The original code is like this, they pass the value in array.

```
$my_meta->addSelect($prefix.'select_field_id',array('selectkey1'=>'Select Value1','selectkey2'=>'Select Value2'),array('name'=> 'My select ', 'std'=> array('selectkey2')));
```

But not getting any value, Any idea where i am wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using third party code to generate those meta boxes, and I am not familiar with how that code works. In fact, based on your question I am not even sure exactly where the code fails. Your description of the problem is inadequate. I can point out that your code is overly complex. It can be simplified considerably:

```
function get_destinations(){
  // Using a post type
  $args = array(
    'type'                     => 'book',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'genre',
  ); 
  $categories = get_terms($args); // changed to get_terms()

  if (!is_wp_error()) {
    $destinations = wp_list_pluck($categories,'cat_name');
    /* Convert to key=>value format
       I doubt this is actually necessary and can probably be omitted
    */
    $destinations = array_combine($destinations,$destinations);
    return $destinations;
  }
}
var_dump(get_destinations());
```

1. Remove the default arguments. You don't need to repeat those.
2. Use `get_terms()` as it returns a proper `WP_Error` object instead
   of only a part of one (at least on my install, which I may have
   broken. I do that periodically). At any rate, `get_terms()` makes
   more since as you are not retrieving "categories" but a custom
   taxonomy.
3. Verify that you have proper term results before trying to use them
4. Use `wp_list_pluck()` to simplify the `foreach`

As far as Core code, I only see three places where this can fail:

1. The post type is wrong
2. The taxonomy is wrong
3. There are not posts in the type/taxonomy

Comment: Acutally to create taxonomy i used wordpress default code, the 3rd party code is used only for extra meta fields.
And the post is correct, taxonomy as well correct, because i get the result when i run on any other page, it not work when i try to run code in functions.php. I will try your code, really thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

It Will work,

```
$cat_args = array(
                      'parent'  => 0,
                      'hide_empty' =>0,
                      'order'    => 'ASC',
                   );
    $categories = get_categories($cat_args);
    foreach($categories as $category){
       echo get_cat_name($category->term_id); 
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little as how it works?

Comment: sure, get_categories hook i was passing parameter parent = > 0 mean all categories(main,sub) hide_empty mean without post be some categories also took.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Parameters section in the WordPress Codex for **get_categories**.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories#Parameters

The **type** parameter only accepts 2 values (post & link) and you are trying to use **accomodation**.

What you are probably wanting is **get_terms**.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

So you will use this instead of **get_categories**.

```
$categories = get_terms('facilitie');
```

For what you are trying to do you probably don't need any **$args** array.

Then in your **foreach** you will just want to change **$cat->cat_name** to **$cat->name**.

Comment: But in this how do i specify which terms i need to retrieve, because i have 3 to 4 type of custom posts, and everyone have 2 to 3 type of taxonomy. So i have to more specify which terms i need.

Comment: I try your suggested code, but it not work either, i show values if i add code in any template, but it not show any value in `fucntions.php` file.

Comment: First, you can get multiple terms by using an array with the name of each term, like `$categories = get_terms(array('term1', 'term2'));`. Second, what is not working when you use this? Are you getting an error? Where is your meta field code at? If that is in your functions.php file (where it should be) then there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: All code are in `functions.php`
I just read a article [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73431/using-get-terms-for-custom-taxonomy-in-functions-php) It says i use `add_action` but still not working for me really really upset.

Comment: here is my new code.
`function retrieve_my_terms(){
 $cats = array();
 global $terms;
 $categories = get_terms( 'destination', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );   
 foreach($categories as $cat){
  $cats[$cat->name] = $cat->name;
 }
 return $cats;
}
add_action('init', 'retrieve_my_terms', 9999);

print_r(retrieve_my_terms());`

When i call this function in templete it show values but not in functions.php which i need

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_cat_val(){

    $taxonomies = array('YOUR_CAT_SLUG');

    $args = array(
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'        => false,
        'hierarchical'      => true 
    ); 

    $terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);

    print_r($terms);

}
```

or

```
global $post;
$term_class = array();

$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'YOUR CAT SLUG' );

if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_class[] = $term->slug;
    }

}
```