# "Invalid taxonomy" with WP_Query's tax_query

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy, tax-query

In WP_Query using tax_query to get products in categories, I recieve "invalid taxonomy" error. Doing that in my child theme.
It seems as if WordPress hasn't loaded taxonomies yet in the child theme, so should I tie that to some hook?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 100000,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $ids,
        ),
    ),
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Where have you put this code? If you're just putting it straight into functions.php then, no, the taxonomies will not be registered yet. But it doesn't make sense to be querying posts outside of a hook like that. What are you trying to do?

Comment: functions.php yea. I'm trying to get products in one taxonomy and add them to another. Should I do it in a plugin instead?

Comment: Or what hook? I'm a bit new to using hooks, it seems so confusing.

Comment: Already found my answer from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73431/using-get-terms-for-custom-taxonomy-in-functions-php